# Protecting routes using React-router-dom and Redux useSelector hook

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am trying to protect some of my routes as in you have to be authenticated in order to get directed to that route. and i am wrapping my Routes in a routerWrapper function that does some validations then after validation it redirects to the proper route.
I am using useSelector to check my authState then upon that if the route isPrivate and isAuthenticated i am redirecting to the route but unsuspectingly at the first React render i am getting that the isAuthenticated is false hence the function is returning the login route. Here's my code

```
const RouteWrapper = ({component, isPrivate, ...props}: IRoutProps) => {
    //Add another property to check isAdmin
    const state = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.auth);
    const {isAuthenticated} = state;
    console.log(isAuthenticated);

    if (isPrivate) {
        if (!state.isAuthenticated) {
            console.log('Private');
            return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        } else {
            return <Route {...props} component={component} />;
        }
    } else {
        if (
            props.path === '/login' &&
            state.isAuthenticated === true &&
            (state.user.type === 'Instructor' || state.user.type === 'Student')
        ) {
            return <Redirect to="/" />;
        } else if (
            props.path === '/admin/login' &&
            state.isAuthenticated &&
            state.user.type === 'Admin'
        ) {
            return <Redirect to="/admin/dashboard" />;
        }
        return <Route {...props} component={component} />;
    }
};
```

Comment: What if you add a `status` in your state that could be either `idle`, `authenticating`, `processed` and then you check if the status is still authenticating then you don't render the Login component? It's like having a loading status.

Comment: @MantasAstra Hey man, i didn't get that idea completely can you tell me how would the if condition look like (i understood that i have to add loading attribute to my state);

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue would be to add something like `status` to your state. Now, this status could be one of the following `idle` (when initialized), `fetching` (when still figuring out if the user is authenticated or not) and `processed` (finished authenticating and now we know the result).

You would need to set the different status in different parts of your code. For example, where you are setting `isAuthenticated`, you would need to set your status to `fetching` before you are setting `isAuthenticated` and once that is resolved you would need to set your status to `processed`.

This way we would know that once the status turns to `processed`, we get our `isAuthenticated` value and then we can proceed with our logic.

If we proceed with adding the status to your state, then we could amend our code to something like this

```js
const RouteWrapper = ({component, isPrivate, ...props}: IRoutProps) => {
    const state = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.auth);
    const {isAuthenticated, status, user} = state;

    if (status === 'processed') {
       if (isPrivate) {
            return isAuthenticated ? 
             (<Route {...props} component={component} />) :
             (<Redirect to="/login" />)
       } else {
        if (
            props.path === '/login' &&
            isAuthenticated &&
            (user.type === 'Instructor' || user.type === 'Student')
        ) {
            return <Redirect to="/" />;
        } else if (
            props.path === '/admin/login' &&
            isAuthenticated &&
            user.type === 'Admin'
        ) {
            return <Redirect to="/admin/dashboard" />;
        }
    
        return <Route {...props} component={component} />;
      }
    }
};
```

This should avoid the first render of the component when the `isAuthenticated` is initialized to `false` before finding out whether the user is authenticated or not.